# create a hyperlink to another tab in the same worksheet having same index in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

- I have three tabs in a excel sheet named MAIN ,SUB1 and SUB2.
- SUB1 contains a TC column with values TC1, TC2,...TC30.
- While SUB2 contains a TC column with values TC31, TC32,...TC90.
- The MAIN tab contains a TC column with values TC1... TC90.

*I need a ***universal formula*** so that if user clicks on TC1(of TC column of SUB1) a hyperlink should take it to TC1 in the TC column of MAIN(and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You need to place it in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    If Left(Target, 2) <> "TC" Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler1
    If UCase(Left(Sh.Name, 3)) = "SUB" Then
        Set wsTarget = Sheets("Main")
    Else
        Set wsTarget = Sheets("SUB" & _
            IIf(CInt(Mid(Target.Value, 3)) <= 30, 1, 2))
    End If
    wsTarget.Activate
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler2

    wsTarget.Cells.Find(Target.Value, wsTarget.Range("A1")).Activate
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler1:
    MsgBox "Cannot identify target sheet from " & Target
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler2:
    MsgBox "Cannot find " & Target & " in sheet " & wsTarget.Name
End Sub
```